# OmniSharp error loading projects with COMReferences in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, msbuild, csproj, visual-studio-code, omnisharp

Having issues loading projects in the new Visual Studio Code that work fine in Visual Studio 2013. I was able to load other projects that don't have COMReferences in Visual Studio Code. Using Windows 7 Enterprise.

Relevant snippet from .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <COMReference Include="DTOLib2">
      <Guid>{DBE2B0CE-6BE9-48FE-8300-6ABE0DB9692B}</Guid>
      <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
      <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
      <Lcid>0</Lcid>
      <WrapperTool>tlbimp</WrapperTool>
      <Isolated>False</Isolated>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </COMReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Relevant snippet from OmniSharp Log:

> [ERROR:OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem] The
>   "ResolveComReference" task could not be instantiated from
>   "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". The domain manager specified by the
>   host could not be instantiated.
>
> [ERROR:OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem] The
>   "ResolveComReference" task has been declared or used incorrectly, or
>   failed during construction. Check the spelling of the task name and
>   the assembly name.

Comment: It is a "your machine is broken" kind of error.  Try another one.

Comment: I tried another COMReference to Include "ASPTypeLibrary", same error.

Comment: Yes, your machine is still broken.

Comment: I want to believe you but.. a coworker has the same error on his machine, would be strange if they were both broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating to Visual Studio Code 0.7.0 solves this issue :)

Comment: Nope. Happens for me in v1.35.1 with OmniShap v1.2.0. :(

Answer (score 1):

The support for MSBuild in OmniSharp isn't as good as we want it to be. There is a summarizing bug for it here: https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-roslyn/issues/202.